# Proportion of 2-generated $p$-groups of a given order

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

For a prime $p$ and positive integer $n$, let $N(p^n)$ be the number of isomorphism classes of groups of order $p^n$, and let $T(p^n)$ be the number of isomorphism classes of groups of order $p^n$ which are 2-generated.

What can we say about the ratio $T(p^n)/N(p^n)$?  Does it always have a limiting value of 1 as $n\rightarrow\infty$, in particular?

Comment: Does "$2$-generated" mean "generated by two elements"?

Comment: @freakish Yes.  And by no fewer, though the number and proportion of 1-generated, aka cyclic, groups wouldn't affect anything if you included them.